# Cannot read property 'tokenizers' of undefined using Typeahead

Tags: typeahead.js

I am using Twitter's "typeahead.js 0.11.1", but I got this error "Cannot read property 'tokenizers' of undefined".  Put my code below, please help me check what I did wrong.

```
paths: {
    'jquery'                : 'assets/lib/jquery.min',
    'underscore'            : 'assets/lib/underscore-min',         
    'backbone'              : 'assets/lib/backbone.min',
    'marionette'            : 'assets/lib/backbone.marionette.min',
    'bootstrap'             : 'assets/lib/bootstrap.min',
    'typeahead'             : 'assets/lib/typeahead.bundle.min',       
},

shim: {
    typeahead:{
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports:'Bloodhound',
        init: function ($) {
            return require.s.contexts._.registry['typeahead.js'].factory( $                          );
        }
    }

}
```

Marionette's view code as below:

```
    define(['jquery',   'marionette','templates', 'underscore','typeahead'], 
    function $,Marionette, templates, _,Bloodhound) {
              'use strict';
          ..................
        onShow:function(){
           var tours = new Bloodhound({
              datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
                  return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
              },
              queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
              remote: {
                  url: '/api/infos?t=ALL',
              }
          });

          // Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
          tours.initialize();
          // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
          $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
              displayKey: 'value',
              source: tours.ttAdapter()
          });

    },
```

Comment: hi! did you solve this? I have the exact same issue

Comment: yes, see here http://www.bluepage.me/case/4/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Backbone/Marionette and a RequireJS configuration. The important point to get right, is to require typeahead.jquery.js and bloodhound.js using separate files. I was using typeahead.bundle.js and it would just not work. Posting this after not a few hours of frustration.